# What to do about gap under outside bath exhaust vent?

Tags: vent

The exhaust vent was broken so I installed a new one. After I finished, the previous homeowner apparently cut the siding too tall, or my new vent is shorter, but I'm left with this raggedy gap at the bottom along the edge of the new vent (ignoring the dirt).

I don't have any siding to match it so any ideas on how to cover that and make it look decent?

[image]

Comment: A thin piece of aluminum or plastic could be slipped in between the siding and the vent and held in place with a couple of small screws.